# Cakephp 3 : How to get max amout row from a table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have table call users , like

```
id name amount   created
1   a   100     6-16-2016
2   b   200     5-16-2016
```

I need max amount full row, I have tried below code but getting syntax error.

```
  $user = $this->Users->find('all',[
         'fields' => array('MAX(Users.amount)  AS amount'),
  ]);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

simplest way

```php
$user = $this->Users->find('all',[
   'fields' => array('amount' => 'MAX(Users.id)'),
]);
```

using select instead of an options array

```php
$user = $this->Users->find()
    ->select(['amount' => 'MAX(Users.id)']);
```

making use of cake SQL functions

```php
$query = $this->Users->find();
$user = $query
    ->select(['amount' => $query->func()->max('Users.id')]);
```

the above three all give the same results

if you want to have a single record you have to call `->first()` on the query object:

```php
$user = $user->first();
$amount = $user->amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method using CakePHP 3:

```
$this->Model->find('all')->select('amount')->hydrate(false)->max('amount')
```

Will result in an array containing the maximum amount in that table column.

Answer (score 0):

Is is better to disable hydration before getting the results, to get the results as an array, instead of entity. Below is a complete example of how to get the results in an array, with distinct steps:

```
//create query
$query = $this->Users->find('all',[
   'fields' => array('amount' => 'MAX(Users.id)'),
]); 

$query->enableHydration(false); // Results as arrays instead of entities
$results = $query->all(); // Get ResultSet that contains array data.
$maxAmount = $results->toList(); // Once we have a result set we can get all the rows
```