# select count of records group by month in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm using `CakePHP 3.x+`

I have to show a graph on the page and thus want to build script for that.

I have to select count of records group by month for current year.

This is what I have tried.

```
$graph = $this->GenerateVideos->find()
        ->select('COUNT(id)', 'MONTH(created)')
        ->where(['YEAR(created)' => date('Y')])
        ->group(['MONTH(created)']);
```

which generates sql like

```
'sql' => 'SELECT GenerateVideos.COUNT(id) AS GenerateVideos__COUNT(`id`) FROM generate_videos GenerateVideos WHERE YEAR(created) = :c0 GROUP BY MONTH(created) ',
'params' => [
    ':c0' => [
        'value' => '2018',
        'type' => null,
        'placeholder' => 'c0'
    ]
],
```

**But this is giving error as**

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`) 
FROM generate_videos GenerateVideos WHERE YEAR(created) = '2018' GROUP BY' at line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp 3 : How to get max amout row from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850117/cakephp-3-how-to-get-max-amout-row-from-a-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an array in your `->select()` value:

```
->select(['COUNT(id)', 'MONTH(created)'])
```

[In the book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data), it always shows an array, and it doesn't appear to be utilizing your second select value.

Or, per [the book here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions), you could try this:

```
$query = $this->GenerateVideos->find();
$query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('id'), 'month' => 'MONTH(created)']);
$query->where(['YEAR(created)' => date('Y')])
$query->group(['month' => 'MONTH(created)']);
```

Comment: I tried below script, but it is giving error as `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`created`) FROM generate_videos GenerateVideos WHERE YEAR(created) = '2018' GRO' at line 1`

Comment: the generated script showing is `SELECT (COUNT(id)) AS `count`, GenerateVideos.MONTH(created) AS GenerateVideos__MONTH(`created`) FROM generate_videos GenerateVideos WHERE YEAR(created) = :c0 GROUP BY MONTH(created) `

Comment: Got it, changing `MONTH(created)` to `'month' => 'MONTH(created)'` is working